# Issue with multiple inheritance Python parent class

Tags: python, pytorch

I have a class `SeriesIDTestLoader` that inherits from both `CSVSeriesIDLoader, CSVTestLoader`.

```
class SeriesIDTestLoader(CSVSeriesIDLoader, CSVTestLoader):
    def __init__(self, series_id_col: str, main_params: dict, return_method: str, return_all=True, forecast_total=336):
        """_summary_

        :param series_id_col: _description_
        :type series_id_col: str
        :param main_params: _description_
        :type main_params: dict
        :param return_method: _description_
        :type return_method: str
        :param return_all: _description_, defaults to True
        :type return_all: bool, optional
        :param forecast_total: _description_, defaults to 336
        :type forecast_total: int, optional
        """
        CSVSeriesIDLoader.__init__(self, series_id_col, main_params, return_method, return_all)
        self.forecast_total = forecast_total

    def get_from_start_date_all(self, forecast_start: datetime, series_id: int = None):
        for df in self.listed_vals:
            dt_row = df[
                df["datetime"] == forecast_start
            ]
            revised_index = dt_row.index[0]
            return self.__getitem__(revised_index - self.forecast_history)
        return self.__getitem__(forecast_start)

    def __getitem__(self, idx: int) -> Tuple[Dict, Dict]:
        return CSVTestLoader.__getitem__(self, idx)
```

I don't understand why this results in this traceback as CSVTestLoader.init is never called and I never call super(). I just want to call init on CSVSeriesIDLoader not on CSVTestLoader (the two have a common parent and just need to be inited once but I need methods from CSVTestLoader that are quite complex)

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/circleci/repo/tests/test_series_id.py", line 53, in test_series_test_loader
    loader_ds1 = SeriesIDTestLoader("PLANT_ID", self.dataset_params, "shit")
  File "/home/circleci/repo/flood_forecast/preprocessing/pytorch_loaders.py", line 664, in __init__
    CSVSeriesIDLoader.__init__(self, series_id_col, main_params, return_method, return_all)
  File "/home/circleci/repo/flood_forecast/preprocessing/pytorch_loaders.py", line 180, in __init__
    super().__init__(**main_params1)
TypeError: CSVTestLoader.__init__() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'df_path' and 'forecast_total'
```

Comment: It's called when `CSVSeriesIDLoader.__init__()` calls `super().__init__()`, because `CSVTestIDLoader` is the next superclass in the MRO.

Comment: You can't use multiple inheritance when the parent classes weren't designed to work together, because they need to know what to pass when calling the superclass's `__init__()`.

Answer (score 1):

[`CSVSeriesIDLoader`](https://github.com/AIStream-Peelout/flow-forecast/blob/master/flood_forecast/preprocessing/pytorch_loaders.py), like any responsible subclass, calls `super().__init__`, and based on the stack trace the next class in your `SeriesIDTestLoader`'s [method resolution order](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#custom-classes) is `CSVTestLoader`.

My first advice is: don't do this. Multiple inheritance is messy on a good day, and unless it's being used with classes specifically designed to be multiple-inherited (like a class meant for use as a mixin, or something like `typing.Generic` that's conveying something other than implementation inheritance), it's a bad idea. In your case, it sounds like your *goal* is to inherit `__init__` from one class and the rest of the implementation from another. That's a recipe for disaster. Consider using [composition over inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance) or some other design pattern that's more sophisticated than "glue these two unrelated things together really hard and hope it stays".

*That being said,* `CSVSeriesIDLoader` does appear to have some customization options available. The constructor looks like this.

> ```
> def __init__(self, series_id_col: str, main_params: dict, return_method: str, return_all=True):
>     """[... docstring omitted ...]"""
>     main_params1 = deepcopy(main_params)
>     if "scaled_cols" not in main_params1:
>         main_params1["scaled_cols"] = main_params1["relevant_cols"].copy()
>         print("The scaled cols are below")
>         print(main_params1["scaled_cols"])
>     main_params1["relevant_cols"].append(series_id_col)
>     super().__init__(**main_params1)
>     [... rest of the method ...]
> ```

So you *might* be able to get away with it using that `main_params` dictionary. Your mileage may vary: I don't know these classes and am going off the source code alone without consideration of long-term consequences. Again, I stress, the correct answer is: Don't do this. But here's how you might do it anyway.

```
def __init__(self, series_id_col: str, main_params: dict, return_method: str, return_all=True, forecast_total=336):
    main_params["df_path"] = value_for_df_path
    main_params["forecast_total"] = value_for_forecast_total
    CSVSeriesIDLoader.__init__(self, series_id_col, main_params, return_method, return_all)
    self.forecast_total = forecast_total
```

Finally, just to make sure there's no doubt.

> I just want to call init on CSVSeriesIDLoader not on CSVTestLoader (the two have a common parent and just need to be inited once

Nope. Hard no. Definitely not. If you have two superclasses, `__init__` them both (in this case, indirectly through the MRO). Not doing so is a great way to make sure your code will collapse in an unmaintainable blaze of glory within roughly two weeks of writing it.